# Simple power program

Tags: c++, loops

I was asking today about power program. So, I almost figure out ho to do it and I want to ask, how to add, numbers before lines(like 1 is; 2 is; and etc.). So the program is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int exponentiation(int base, int exponent);

int main(void)
{

 for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
   cout << exponentiation(i, i) << '\n';
}

int exponentiation(int base, int exponent){

int result = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < exponent; ++i)
result = result * base;
return result;
}
```

Output goes line by line

```
                      ....     
                      ....... 
                      ..............
```

and I want to make it looks like this:

```
                      1 is ....     
                      2 is ....... 
                      3 is ..............
```

I was trying to make a cout loop and add in code above, but it doesn't work:

```
           #include<iostream>
           using namespace std;
           int exponentiation(int base, int exponent);


         int main(void) {

         for(int c = 1; c < 10; c++)
         {
           cout << c << " is ";
           for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
           cout << exponentiation(i, i) << '\n';
            cout << endl;
           }

           }

           int exponentiation(int base, int exponent) {
           int result = 1;
           for (int i = 0; i < exponent; ++i)
           result = result * base;
           return result;
              }
```

Comment: For future reference, "it doesn't work" is not acceptable as a problem description.

Comment: BTW I'm not sure I understand how you managed to get a sequence of dots to be your output.

Comment: i^i isn't the exponential function. And 10^10 is too big for `int` on most systems; you might want to stop at 9^9.

Comment: (If the output is a "unary number" sequence of dots, stopping at 3^3 or 4^4 might be a better idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the perfect loop ready and waiting in your original program. Why do you need to add a new one? All you need to do is add stuff to the line on which you print `exponentiation(i, i)`:

```
int main()
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
      cout << (i+1) << "is: " << exponentiation(i, i) << '\n';
}
```

It's really as easy as that!